# Spring MVC routing to wrong controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a web application in SpringMVC, After login I want to point it to "/" but its always pointing me to /home.

```
<security:form-login
                login-page="/home/login"
                default-target-url="/"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                authentication-failure-url="/auth/failed"/>
```

here is homecontroller.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@SessionAttributes({"loginModel"})

    public class HomeController {

        @Autowired
        private LoginModelService loginModelService;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String loadHome(Model model, Principal principal) {

            model.addAttribute("loginModel", loginModelService.getLoginModelByUserLoginName(principal.getName()));
            return "index";
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/home")
        public String showHome(Model model, Principal principal) {

            model.addAttribute("loginModel", loginModelService.getLoginModelByUserLoginName(principal.getName()));
            return "system/home";
        }
    }
```

After login showHome method is being called instead of loadHome

Comment: Try to replace "/" with "./" in your default target url

Comment: Error: defaulttarget must start with /